# Magnolia CMS export import users

Tags: configuration, content-management-system, magnolia

Goal: I would like to export Users from a given Magnolia CMS instance & then import them in another one.

---

#### What I tried

**Export from the given Magnolia CMS instance**

1. Open `admin central`
2. Click on `Tools > JCR Tools` in the `App Launcher`
   [image: "Tools > JCR Tools" in Magnolia CMS "App Launcher"]
3. Click on the `Exporter` tab
4. Select `users` workspace & type **`/admin`** for the path
   [image: "Exporter" tab of "Tools > JCR Tools" in Magnolia CMS "App Launcher"]
5. Click on `Execute`

**Then import in the other instance**

1. Open `admin central`
2. Click on `Tools > JCR Tools` in the `App Launcher`
3. Click on the `Importer` tab
4. Select `users` workspace & type `/admin` for the path
5. Upload the file exported previously (see steps of "Export from the given Magnolia CMS instance"
6. Click on `Execute`

However, I end up with an `admin` parent folder in the `Users` tab (under `Security`).

---

#### Resources

[Importing and exporting JCR data](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Importing+and+exporting+JCR+data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you explained makes absolutely sense. When you export the JCR-Structure the exported node is `admin`, when you import it under the path `/admin`, you will have the JCR-structure `/admin/admin`.

If you import at `/`, you will face the problem, that a folder called `admin` already exists, the imported folder will therefore be renamed to `/admin[2]` (and is therefore invisible in the security app).

Possible (imperfect) solutions:

1. exporting & importing the user nodes one by one
2. export from `/admin`. Then import in `/admin`. After importing: move the users one folder up using the JCR App (seems not to be possible in the security app)
3. export from `/admin`. Then remove the `/admin` using a text (or XML) editor. Import in `/admin`.
4. before importing, delete the admin-folder (in the JCR App) , in case your users are all the same

---

#### Solution 3 explained

This solution has the huge advantage of simplicity: all you need is a text editor.

1. Edit the exported files (on a copy):

   - 1.a. Delete line number 2 until the line containing the first user

[image]

- 1.b. Insert instead the following (a root folder):

  ```
      <sv:node sv:name="jcr:root" xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
         <sv:value>rep:root</sv:value>
      </sv:property>
  ```

  2. Then import the file (Tools | Import) with options:

     Repository : Users
       Base Path : /admin
       Keep version : unticked
       File : chose corresponding file
       UUID : Remove existing nodes with the same id **(you may want to change this)**

Comment: I would go for the first one (export/import one-by-one), but using a Groovy script.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the clarifications on this problem. I edited your answer to add further info on an additional solution. Hope that's ok for you

Comment: I personally favour solution 2, as it's the fastest (just a few clicks more), if there are just a few users.
A 5th possible solution could be to use magnolias publishing functionality (https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Publishing) to move user nodes from one magnolia author instance to another magnolia author instance. But this is probably not wanted/possible in many cases.